# I can't remove GRUB from windows 8, How to remove it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, grub

I'm kind of newbee in using UBUNTU and a little curious about what does it do, so I used my old HDD to use it as an external storage and install UBUNTU on it. After installing it, using it for a little why lets say for about 3 days I've had some problems and decided to remove it. So I followed the steps that I found on how to remove it I've tried disks app in UBUNTU just to remove the installation but after doing that the GRUB BOOTLOADER won't come off I've tried removing the old HDD in  thought of that it might be the reason. After doing that I still get the same problem, I've also tried refreshing my pc just to test if it will go back as the same as before but still no luck. ( [Me and this guy have the same problem different scenario](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592314/remove-grub-from-its-own-partition) 
Also I couldn't find the UBUNTU partition on device manager on windows even though the old HDD is connected. 
I really need help guys. 
I could provide images as this discussion moves on in order to solve the problem.

Comment: 'Me and this guy have the same problem...' Have you tried **the answer given**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first bit about removing grub..

1: Put you windows installation DVD in your optical drive and boot from it

2: On the installation screen where it asks you to install windows, click on "Repair Your Computer" on the lower left corner of your screen

3: Now go to command prompt(It probably will show a window saying "Trying to repair windows automatically", close it) and type bootrec/fixmbr

4: after it finishes GRUB is gone and you can now boot into windows directly

Unfortunately Windows doesnt recognise Linux type partitions at all. If you want to access it, there are several bits of software that you can try. Have a look at this link

http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

**If you just want to delete the UBUNTU partiton carry on with this**

5: you have a ubuntu partition left in your computer, that doesn't show in "My Computer", to access that, right click on "My Computer" and Select "Manage" and go to "Disk Management"

6: Select the ubuntu partition and format it to a file system that windows can use.

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks took me a while to respond to this answer! :D Been busy in work.

Answer (score 0):

first of all burn a windows os in ur USB.
then, install this partition manager

[mini tool partition manager](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)

then try to remove the ubuntu partition by selecting the partition and pressing delete and then apply.

secondly u will see ur bootloader gone..

then boot with the windows live USB and select repair windows...
then run command prompt from recovery console
then type these lines

1. bootrec /fixmbr
2. bootrec /fixboot

reboot ur system....it should work fine

(let me know the consequences....if it dosen't work i would research further)

Comment: Thanks took me a while to respond to this answer! :D Been busy in work.